# drools rules in condition in List of custom objects

Tags: drools

I have student class which has list of departments associated.

```
public class Student {

    private String name;
    private String desc;
    private List<Department> department = new ArrayList<Department>();
}

public class Department {

    private String name;
    private String desc;
}
```

I am trying write rule in Drools. Rule is like - If a student belong to certain departments then take an action. I am not able to figure out the right way to do it. One i had written below does not work. I understand it works if its List of String. Is there way to do the contains on custom object.

```
rule "Language"

when
    $student : Student(department contains "English" && department contains "French")

then
    System.out.println("Belongs to Language");
```

end

Code to invoke rules

```
                Student student  = new Student();
                student.setName("John");
                Department a1 = new Department();
                a1.setName("English");
                student.addDepartment(a1);
                Department a2 = new Department();
                a2.setName("French");
                student.addDepartment(a2);
                System.out.println("Student :" + student);
                ksession.insert(student);  
                ksession.fireAllRules();
```

I am using Drools 6.2 version.

Answer (score 2):

Looking for a String in a `List<Department>` isn't going to work. You'll have to look for a member where the `name` field is one of these two values.

```
rule "Language"
when
  $student: Student( $dep: department )
  Department( name == "French" || == "English",
              this memberOf $dep )
then
  System.out.println("Belongs to Language");
end
```

**Edit:** You need to insert the DEpartment objects as facts as well.

If the student has to have both languages, use

```
rule "Language"
when
  $student: Student( $dep: department )
  Department( name == "French", this memberOf $dep )
  Department( name == "English", this memberOf $dep )
then
  System.out.println("Belongs to Language");
end
```

Comment: Thanks laune. I tried executing this rule, but it does not print the sysout in action part. Not sure what is the issue. Also my condition was student should belong to both english and french dept. then he belongs to Language department. If he belongs to English and Maths this rule should not be fired. Updated the code in question.

Comment: Well, the code you've added shows that you did not insert the Department objects as facts. Edited the answer.